# Macsec and Optics

Tags: optics

Do Macsec have any bearing with respect to optics? Wanted to understand, if Macsec is enabled, will the optics perform any additional task or they are transparent and it doesn’t bother if Macsec is enabled or not?

Thx.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about fiber optic transceivers commonly used in network equipment, the answer is MACsec has no impact on them.  MACsec is a layer 2 protocol, while transceivers are simply layer 1, converting electrical signals into light and vice-versa.